# phonegap changes type of error after every run

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

why does phone gap changes error after every-time it is compiled.
some times it runs without any error and then the same code gives silly errors such parse error of function not found despite no changes made to the code.

here is the code which gives different errors at each compile

---

```
   <html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="wrapper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="natiweb.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
function loadcontact()
{
    alert('load');
    //  navigator.contacts.find("*",contactSuccess, contactError);
    // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="Bob";
    options.multiple=true; 
    var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
**navigator.contacts.find(fields, contactSuccess onError, options);**
    window.location = "download.html";
}

function contactSuccess(contacts)
{
    alert('success');
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) 
        {
            console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
        }
}
function contactError(error) 
{
    alert('error');
}

</script>
</head>
<body class="index">
<p></p>
<h1 class="natiweb">NatiWeb</h1>
<form name ="choicepage" id="wrapper" >
<table id="wrapper" >
<tr><td>
<table align="center">
<tr></tr>

<p><b>Select Upload/Download</b></p>
<select name="upload/download">
<option selected >Upload</option>
<option>Download</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/contact-icon.png" height="15"> Contacts </td>
<td><input name="opt" type="checkbox" value="Contacts"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="Back"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Next1" onclick="loadcontact();"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

errors 1:SyntaxError: Parse error at file:///android_asset/www/choice.html:22 here line 22 is marked in bold

Answer (score 0):

You have comma missing on that line.

One more thing, you should redirect the user after you receive the success/error callback, not before.

```
function loadcontact()
{
    alert('load');
    //  navigator.contacts.find("*",contactSuccess, contactError);
    // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="Bob";
    options.multiple=true; 
    var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, contactSuccess, onError, options);

}

function contactSuccess(contacts)
{
    alert('success');
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) 
        {
            console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
        }
    window.location = "download.html";
}
function contactError(error) 
{
    alert('error');
    window.location = "download.html";
}
```